# python gc.collect() in loop

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Can anyone provide an explanation for why this is happening?

```
>>> for i2 in range(10):
...     print i2
...     gc.collect()
...
0
0
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
0
6
0
7
0
8
0
9
0
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of the `gc.collect()` is the [number of unreachable objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html):

> **`gc.collect([generation])`**
>   With no arguments, run a full collection. The optional argument generation may be an integer specifying which generation to collect (from `0` to `2`). A `ValueError` is raised if the generation number is invalid. ***The number of unreachable objects found is returned.***

When you enter that program into Python interactively, the result of all those calls is being output by the REPL (read-eval-***print*** loop). This is no different to when you enter `42+7` into Python interactively and it echoes back `49` despite there being *no* indication you wanted it printed (with, for example, a `print` call).

This output you're seeing is therefore all the zero return values from `gc.collect()`, interspersed amongst your "real" output from the range printing.

If you ran this as a *real* script, you'd only see the numbers `0..9` since the REPL is not involved. Or you could equally prevent the return value from being output by doing something with it, such as:

```
>>> for i2 in range(4):
...     print i2
...     junk = gc.collect()
...
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Do you also know why you get one print per iterator step? I would have expected just one additional print for the last expression. Is this a "feature" of the for loop?

Comment: @mkiever, *each* time thru the loop you print the current value *and* the result from `gc.collect` is printed by REPL. The collect is within the loop rather than after it.

Comment: @paxdiablo, never knew REPL extends to some compound statements. Seems not to extend to functions/classes though. Only in global scope then?